# Is there a function in sheets that can calculate the total of multiple item in the same field?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

| Name | Price | Basket | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | A/B/C | 6 |
| B | 2 | B/C | 5 |
| C | 3 | A/C | 4 |
|  |  | A/A/B | 4 |
|  |  | C/C/C | 9 |

Column A and B are the name and value of each item and column C contains the list of one or multiple items and I would like to calculate the total in column D base on the item contained in column C and their respective prices.

I have tried multiple solution but to no avail,
"=SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FLATTEN(SPLIT(JOIN("/", B:B), "/")), C:A, 2, FALSE), 0))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted your formula so that it uses the SPLIT on the specific cell in C, and use that value to VLOOKUP:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(INDEX(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(C2,"/"), A:C, 2, FALSE), 0)))
```

You can also use it as an array for the whole column:

```
=BYROW(C2:C,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",SUM(IFERROR(INDEX(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(each,"/"), A:C, 2, FALSE), 0))))))
```

[image: 1. List item]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, it worked for me in this instance, but I have encountered other condition where I have to account for, I have posted the question in another thread in a clearer explanation with the data, can you help me out once more? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77644632/5324423

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative solution is by using `XLOOKUP Function`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(XLOOKUP(SPLIT(C2,"/"),A:A,B:B)))
```

[image]