# Seeking Assistance in Google Sheets: Formulating Functions for Profit Calculation with Multiple Identifiers (Order No.) and Keys (Invoice No.)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

| Invoice No | CREDIT |
| --- | --- |
| A001 | 290 |
| B001 | 210 |
| C001 | 350 |
| A001 | 250 |
| B001/C001 | 210 |
| A001 | 220 |

| Order No | DEBIT | PROFIT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A001 | 300 | 10 |
| C001 | 320 | -30 |
| B001/A001 | 450 | -10 |
| A001/B001/C001 | 490 | 60 |

I have two sets of financial records in Excel—one for credit transactions with Invoice No and the corresponding amounts, and the other for debit transactions with Order No, debit amounts, and profits. I am using the following formula to calculate the profit by matching Order No and Invoice No:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(INDEX(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(C3,"/"), K:O, 5, FALSE), 0))) -G3
```

This formula works well when Order No and Invoice No are not unique and may reoccur, and when some Order No consist of multiple Invoice No. However, I am facing a challenge when some data has multiple Invoice No lumped together as well. In these cases, the current formula doesn't fully address the condition. I am seeking guidance on how to modify the formula to handle scenarios where multiple Invoice No are lumped together with Order No. The profit is calculated by subtracting the credit amount from the debit amount that matches both Invoice No and Order No with the same sequence of appearance.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-MjTf_Ix_-imrbFNqXEG_5RQgQnuDJgPb7CjgKSCu8E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-MjTf_Ix_-imrbFNqXEG_5RQgQnuDJgPb7CjgKSCu8E/edit?usp=sharing

ty for your response, this is the sheet

Comment: Do provide some backend explanation(**in super basic way**) on how arrived at 3569.23 as expected output in H14?! and are we to assume that `A20231108/A` → ***A20231108+A20231108A*** & `A20230922/0922A` → ***A20230922+A20230922A***

Comment: How about the second part of the question posed above. Is there going to be partial code in some scenarios like in C21, C22 which needs to be assumed as full code and all bcoz again C14 and C17 needs to have full code when lumped together?!

Comment: Sorry again I did not see the second part of your question earlier, yes it's exactly as you said. But I will change all the shorten code to the full code manually. I have updated the test sheet

Comment: Why `B001/A001`'s profit is ``-10``? Do note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.  More importantly, your question depends on external links. For eg, where is G3? What is K:O? Anyone should be able to understand your question without visiting external links. If not, the question is liable to be closed.

Comment: B001/A001's profit is 450 subtracting the sum of first instance of B001 (210) and the second instance of A001 (250) = 460, which is -10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(cred_,reduce(tocol(,1),K3:index(K:K,match(,0/(K:K<>""))),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Σ,split(c,"/"),Λ,offset(c,,4)/counta(Σ),hstack(tocol(Σ),wrapcols(Λ,counta(Σ),Λ)))))),
     map(C3:C,G3:G,lambda(Σ,deb_,if(Σ="",,ifna(reduce(,split(Σ,"/"),lambda(a,c,a+chooserows(filter(index(cred_,,2),index(cred_,,1)=c),counta(ifna(filter(C3:Σ,regexmatch(regexreplace(C3:Σ,"[()]","_"),"\b"&regexreplace(c,"[()]","_")&"\b")))))))-deb_,"-")))))
```

[image]

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @rockinfreakshow Hi, is it possible to modify the formula in a way that would allow me to manually enter the value for certain cells? because there's certain exception where we would need to manually calculate the profits. Also I have discovered that if the Order No is : A/A/B, while on the invoice side is A, A/B, the formula would sum up the invoice by A + A/B + A/B twice, which gives a wrong final value, is there anyway to resolve this?

Comment: converted the array-style formula into single-cell-drag-style formula and added it to Column_P of the test sheet

Comment: @rockinfreakshow thanks again, I couldn't quite get it to work with the single-cell-drag-style formula, but I got it to work by adding another column and just copy the value over. But I discovered some occasion where the formula wouldn't compute the profit correctly, can you have a look for me? I have updated the test sheet with the same data.

Comment: google regex re2 only works with text(not numbers). your previous sample data has only text based order IDs & now it seems to have numbers. hence the issue; So I changed `C3:Σ` to `to_text(C3:Σ)`, `c` to `to_text(c)` & you have the output as usual...

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

You have two data sets: one for order numbers ("DEBITPROFITA") and another for invoice numbers ("CREDITA").
Both data sets have reoccurring entries for the same order or invoice, potentially with different amounts.
You want to calculate the profit for each entry, accounting for both reoccurring orders and combined invoices.
Your function:

It uses IFERROR(INDEX(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(C3,"/"), K:O, 5, FALSE), 0)) to extract the corresponding amount from the "DEBITPROFITA" data based on the order number (split from cell C3 by "/").
Then, it subtracts the cost associated with the entry (presumably stored in cell G3) to calculate the profit.
Challenges:

The function relies on the sequence of entries to identify re-occurrences, which might not be reliable in all cases.
It doesn't handle combined invoices effectively.
Possible solutions:

Unique identifier: Instead of relying on sequence, consider adding a unique identifier (e.g., product ID) to each entry in both data sets. This would allow accurate identification of re-occurrences and simplify the lookup process.

Hash table approach: Build a hash table with order numbers as keys and amounts as values. This would allow efficient lookup of amounts for any given order, regardless of its sequence or combination with other invoices.

Dedicated function for combined invoices: Create a separate function to handle combined invoices. This function could iterate through the split invoice numbers within a single order and calculate the total cost based on individual invoice amounts.

Additional recommendations:

Document your function clearly, explaining the logic and assumptions used.
Use error handling to gracefully handle situations where values are missing or invalid.
Consider testing your function with various edge cases to ensure accuracy.
By addressing the challenges and implementing the suggested solutions, you should be able to achieve a more robust and reliable function for calculating profits from your reoccurring and combined order data.

I hope this analysis helps you further refine your function and achieve the desired results. Remember, feel free to provide more details about your data or specific challenges if you need further assistance.